# What time do iTunes Connect daily sales reports begin and end?

Tags: app-store-connect

The iOS app store and iTunes Connect generate daily sales reports for apps. The reports say, for example, that I have 15 app purchases and 10 in-app purchases. What time of day do these reports begin and end? E.g. does it count sales from midnight PST to midnight PST, or a different time frame? I am interested in tracking the in-app purchase receipts that I process of my server (to verify that they are valid) vs. the iTunes Connect sales reports to see if the numbers line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is midnight PST/PDT to midnight PST/PDT.

Keep in mind that your numbers will not always match the official reports. It all depends on the timing of when credit card transactions complete and money is actually posted, etc.